# How to insert particular element of json data in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

How to insert all the  "story" (only) from the json formated data in the MySQL database using PHP. I would like to insert all the story in a single field. Please help.

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'story' => 'akhilesh shared Filmydrama\'s video.',
    'created_time' => 
    array (
      'date' => '2016-02-12 14:05:15.000000',
      'timezone_type' => 1,
      'timezone' => '+00:00',
    ),
    'id' => '10154521329397892_10154545385862892',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'story' => 'akhilesh shared Kya Yehi Hain Acche Din?\'s video.',
    'created_time' => 
    array (
      'date' => '2016-02-12 03:34:32.000000',
      'timezone_type' => 1,
      'timezone' => '+00:00',
    ),
    'id' => '10154521329397892_10154544563382892',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'story' => 'akhilesh shared a link.',
    'created_time' => 
    array (
      'date' => '2016-02-12 03:28:09.000000',
      'timezone_type' => 1,
      'timezone' => '+00:00',
    ),
    'id' => '10154521329397892_10154544555572892',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'message' => 'R.I.P Jaihind',
    'story' => 'akhilesh shared The Hindu\'s post.',
    'created_time' => 
    array (
      'date' => '2016-02-11 07:46:59.000000',
      'timezone_type' => 1,
      'timezone' => '+00:00',
    ),
    'id' => '10154521329397892_10154542597202892',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'story' => 'akhilesh posted from Change.org.',
    'created_time' => 
    array (
      'date' => '2016-02-11 05:09:08.000000',
      'timezone_type' => 1,
      'timezone' => '+00:00',
    ),
    'id' => '10154521329397892_10154542373792892',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'message' => 'Johnson & Johnson Finally Admits: Their Baby Products Contain Cancer-Causing Chemicals | ',
    'created_time' => 
    array (
      'date' => '2016-02-11 01:38:33.000000',
      'timezone_type' => 1,
      'timezone' => '+00:00',
    ),
    'id' => '10154521329397892_10154542027992892',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'story' => 'akhilesh shared a link.',
    'created_time' => 
    array (
      'date' => '2016-02-09 17:16:07.000000',
      'timezone_type' => 1,
      'timezone' => '+00:00',
    ),
    'id' => '10154521329397892_10154538723082892',
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'story' => 'akhilesh shared The Guardian\'s video.',
    'created_time' => 
    array (
      'date' => '2016-02-09 01:45:30.000000',
      'timezone_type' => 1,
      'timezone' => '+00:00',
    ),
    'id' => '10154521329397892_10154537304507892',
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'story' => 'akhilesh shared The Frustrated Engineer\'s video.',
    'created_time' => 
    array (
      'date' => '2016-02-08 01:18:59.000000',
      'timezone_type' => 1,
      'timezone' => '+00:00',
    ),
    'id' => '10154521329397892_10154534663442892',
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    'story' => 'akhilesh shared 24 Ghanta\'s post.',
    'created_time' => 
    array (
      'date' => '2016-02-07 15:03:28.000000',
      'timezone_type' => 1,
      'timezone' => '+00:00',
    ),
    'id' => '10154521329397892_10154533473037892',
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
    'story' => 'akhilesh shared a link.',
    'created_time' => 
    array (
      'date' => '2016-02-07 14:54:39.000000',
      'timezone_type' => 1,
      'timezone' => '+00:00',
    ),
    'id' => '10154521329397892_10154533459592892',
  ),
)
```

```
$total_posts = array();
        $array = json_encode($total_posts, true);
        $my_arr = json_decode($array, true);

    echo "<pre>";
    $data = var_export($my_arr);
    echo "</pre>";

    $story = $data;
    foreach( $my_arr as $row ) $story .= " {$row[story]}";
    $story = trim( $story);


    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users1 (name, token, message) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss",$name, $accessToken, $story);


    if ( !$stmt ) {
    printf('errno: %d, error: %s', $db->errno, $db->error);
    die;
    }
    else
    {
        $stmt->execute();
        echo "New record created successfully !!";
    }

    $stmt->close();
    $db->close();
```

The above code give me blank filed in database.

**After EDIT**
is it possible to store *'id'* and *'story'* in one field, like id:123 story:'xyzabc' should be stored as 123  **tab** xyzabc **newline** in one field. So finally I can get all the story and corresponding story-id in one field where story and story-id are separated with tab

```
$story = $data;
    foreach( $my_arr as $row ) 

            $story .= " $row[message]\n";

    $message_id = $data;
    foreach( $my_arr as $row ) 

            $message_id .= " $row[id]\n";
```

The above one is giving all the id's of the fetched data, but I would like to have the id of story only

Comment: Why you mix procedural and oo styles in db queries? What driver use you: mysql, mysqli or pdo? Also you have to bind or escape your query.

Comment: @fusion3k, I am using mysql

Comment: I don't think that `$db->query()` is valid `mysql` call! If you are starting now with php, **please don't use mysql**: it's derecated and **completely removed** in php v. 7! So, when you will upgrade php, you will have to rewrite all your code! Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead. You also have to bind yr query, because yr string is complex and can contains chars in conflict with mysql syntax (i.e. single quotation). See a [basic PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Comment: @fusion3k, Sorry its mysqli, i referred from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: In the same tutorial, see at [Prepared Statements](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) chapter, and let me know if they help you

Comment: ` $total_posts = array();
 $my_arr = json_decode($array, true);

 echo "<pre>";
 $data = var_export($my_arr);
 echo "</pre>";

 $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users1 ((name, token, message) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
 $stmt->bind_param($name, $accessToken, $lastname, $data);
 $result_insert = mysql_query($sql);
 if ($db->query($stmt) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully !!";
 } else {
     echo "Error: " . $stmt . "<br>" . $db->error;
 }

 $stmt->close();
 $db->close()`

Comment: @fusion3k , not working !

Comment: edit original post, don't add multiple line code in comments! What error you have?

Comment: i.e. this is not valid: `$db->prepare("INSERT INTO users1 ((name, token, message) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")` where you close the first parenthesis inside the query?

Comment: @fusion3k, is this $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users1 ((name, token, message) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

Comment: $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users1 (name, token, message) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

Comment: simply count parenthesis: if they are odd, that's an error

Comment: changes the parenthesis! no effect

Comment: updated my answer. Please pay attention at your own code. Check errors, double-check variables, field and table names, syntax code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$story = '';
foreach( $array as $row ) $story .= " {$row[story]}";
$story = trim( $story);
```

`$story` now contains the full story that you can add to database.

#### Edit (after question edit)

It seems you are coding randomly. Pay attention at your own work:

```
$total_posts = array();
$my_arr = json_decode($array, true);

echo "<pre>";
$data = var_export($my_arr);
echo "</pre>";

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users1 ((name, token, message) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
```

In the mysql query you open 3 parenthesis, but close only two of them: you can open only one parenthesis after `user1`.
Use `if( ! $stmt = $db->prepare(...) ) die("{$db->error}");` to retrieve `prepare` error.

```
$stmt->bind_param($name, $accessToken, $lastname, $data);
```

What variables you want pass to `bind_parameter`? You want insert values in three fields and then pass four parameters? Or `$name` contains types of binding? I doubt that this is so. Read careful the [bind_param syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) and then change your bind in a similar way: `$stmt->bind_param('sss', $name, $accessToken, $data);`. **“Similar way”** means that you don't have to copy-and-paste, but understand the syntax and use it depending of your context.

```
$result_insert = mysql_query($sql);
```

What is this `mysql_query`? A *nostalgic* decoration? Remove it.

```
if ($db->query($stmt) === TRUE) {
```

You have really read the “Prepared statements” W3 tutorial? Where in this tutorial there are the `->query()` method? Nowhere. With prepared statements you have to use `$stmt->execute()` (without arguments).

```
echo "New record created successfully !!";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $stmt . "<br>" . $db->error;
```

You can't print out in this way an Object of class mysqli_stmt (`$stmt`): simply remove it and echo only `$db->error`

```
}

$stmt->close();
$db->close()
```

Comment: Hi, I did the same but nothing happen in database,                                   $total_posts = array();
$array = json_encode($total_posts, true);
$my_arr = json_decode($array, true);
echo "<pre>";
$data = var_export($my_arr);
echo "</pre>";
  $story = $data;
  foreach( $array as $row ) {
   $story .= " {$row[story]}";
  }
  $story = trim( $story);
$sql = "INSERT INTO users1 (message) VALUES ('{$story}')";
$result_insert = mysql_query($sql);
if ($db->query($sql) === TRUE) {
   echo "New record created successfully !!";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $db->error;
}
$db->close();

Comment: 1) check the final `$story` content before adding it to db; 2) edit your question showing your db insertion code. We are not soothsayers...

Comment: @user1328007 **edit your question** adding code, please! Not in the comment.

Comment: @user1328007 at first sight it seems ok. but if you don't have result there are a problem. Sorry but I don't know your db structure, your complete array, the content of variables etc... you have to double-check all, step by step, to isolate the problem. It's a hard job, but it's the programmer's common job... also you can try to print out the query before executing it and manually paste it into phpmyadimin to see if it works. But all are only speculations, you have to find the error by yourself, I suspect.

Comment: will this solve the issue to store the multiple "story" in a single database field?

Comment: my database structure is name varchar(50) , token text , message text

Comment: I have tested now your script and it's fine. I have correctly added the data from your array to db. So the problem reside in some name typo or similar. **triple check** your variables and names(table, fileds). Also: how you check if the record is added to db? Check it through _phpMyAdmin_, maybe the error is in the retrieve routine, not in the insert.

Comment: are you able to insert the data say, "story" in your database?

Comment: Yes, I insert the ‘story’ string in the database

Comment: I have done the exactly what I edited but it does not showing the result. Could you please paste your code here?

Comment: I have deleted the script. BTW, it is in the answer. **Have you checked** the result through phpMyAdmin?

Comment: fusion3k, I have some query regarding the code, a)  is it possible to store the each message in each line. It seems that trim() keep all in single line. b) $data = var_export($my_arr); this just returns a parsable string representation of a variable and displayed on the screen, is it possible not to displayed the string on the screen, but it will effect on the database only.

Comment: is it the ob_start() and ob_end_clean();?

Comment: Have tried with this $text = str_replace('\n', '<br />', $text); but not able to get the solution !

Comment: is it possible to store 'id' and 'story' in one field, like id:123 story:'xyzabc' should be stored as 123  <tab><tab> xyzabc <newline> in one field. So finally I can get all the story and corresponding story-id in one field where story and story-id are separated with <tab>

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But why? Storing id in separate field is more flexible.

Comment: corresponding story id I would like to store

Comment: this one is giving all the id's but I would like to have corresponding story id only `$story = $data;
 foreach( $my_arr as $row ) 
  
   $story .= " $row[message]\n";

 $message_id = $data;
 foreach( $my_arr as $row ) 
  
   $message_id .= " $row[id]\n";`

Comment: please ask new appropriate question and add more details

Comment: I don't know your db struct and your html, but I think yes. The output is as expected?

Comment: I have ask question here, please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35487882/how-to-check-the-array-keys-in-php-to-store-array-values-in-mysql?noredirect=1#comment58669978_35487882