# How to check the array keys in php to store array values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How to check the array keys in php to store array values in mysql. I am trying to store the "id" if the array have ("message") AND ("message" AND "story") key.

**Array**

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'message' => 'Insane!!!!!',
    'story' => 'Ankan shared TIMES NOW\'s video.',
    'created_time' => 
    array (
      'date' => '2016-02-16 17:15:49.000000',
      'timezone_type' => 1,
      'timezone' => '+00:00',
    ),
    'id' => '10154521329397892_10154555849367892',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'story' => 'Ankan shared Filmydrama\'s video.',
    'created_time' => 
    array (
      'date' => '2016-02-12 14:05:15.000000',
      'timezone_type' => 1,
      'timezone' => '+00:00',
    ),
    'id' => '10154521329397892_10154545385862892',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'story' => 'Ankan shared Kya Yehi Hain Acche Din?\'s video.',
    'created_time' => 
    array (
      'date' => '2016-02-12 03:34:32.000000',
      'timezone_type' => 1,
      'timezone' => '+00:00',
    ),
    'id' => '10154521329397892_10154544563382892',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'story' => 'Ankan shared a link.',
    'created_time' => 
    array (
      'date' => '2016-02-12 03:28:09.000000',
      'timezone_type' => 1,
      'timezone' => '+00:00',
    ),
    'id' => '10154521329397892_10154544555572892',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'message' => 'R.I.P Jaihind',
    'story' => 'Ankan shared The Hindu\'s post.',
    'created_time' => 
    array (
      'date' => '2016-02-11 07:46:59.000000',
      'timezone_type' => 1,
      'timezone' => '+00:00',
    ),
    'id' => '10154521329397892_10154542597202892',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'story' => 'Ankan posted from Change.org.',
    'created_time' => 
    array (
      'date' => '2016-02-11 05:09:08.000000',
      'timezone_type' => 1,
      'timezone' => '+00:00',
    ),
    'id' => '10154521329397892_10154542373792892',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'message' => 'Johnson & Johnson Finally Admits: Their Baby Products Contain Cancer-Causing Chemicals | ',
    'created_time' => 
    array (
      'date' => '2016-02-11 01:38:33.000000',
      'timezone_type' => 1,
      'timezone' => '+00:00',
    ),
    'id' => '10154521329397892_10154542027992892',
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'story' => 'Ankan shared a link.',
    'created_time' => 
    array (
      'date' => '2016-02-09 17:16:07.000000',
      'timezone_type' => 1,
      'timezone' => '+00:00',
    ),
    'id' => '10154521329397892_10154538723082892',
  ),
```

I tried  with the following code, but it is not giving anything.

```
$total_posts = array();
    $posts_response = $posts_request->getGraphEdge();
    if($fb->next($posts_response)) {
        $response_array = $posts_response->asArray();
        $total_posts = array_merge($total_posts, $response_array);
        while ($posts_response = $fb->next($posts_response)) {  
            $response_array = $posts_response->asArray();
            $total_posts = array_merge($total_posts, $response_array);  
        }
        $array = json_encode($total_posts, true);

    } else {
        $posts_response = $posts_request->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
        print_r($posts_response);
    }


    $my_arr = json_decode($array, true);

    ob_start();
    $data = var_export($my_arr);
    ob_end_clean();


    /*$story = $data;
    foreach( $my_arr as $row ) 

            $story .= " $row[message]\n";        

    $message_id = $data;
    foreach( $my_arr as $row ) 

            $message_id .= " $row[id]\n";*/


 $total_posts[0] = array('message', 'story', 'created_time', array('date', 'timezone_type', 'timezone'),'id');


    foreach ($total_posts as $row) {
      if (isset($row['story']) {
        if (isset($row['message']) {
          $message_id .= "$row[id]\n";
          $story .= " $row[message]\n";
        } else {
          // only story
        }
      } else {
        $message_id .= "$row[id]\n";
          $story .= " $row[message]\n";
      }
    }
```

I would like to get the output like

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
id                                   | Messages
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 10154521329397892_10154555849367892 | Insane!!!!!
 10154521329397892_10154542597202892 || R.I.P Jaihind
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

The above id will be associated with the message if and only if "message" key exists in the array.

Comment: hmm.. you have to concat all `$row['id']` to `$message_id`, i.e. finally you have a string like `id\n10154521329397892_10154545385862892\n10154521329397892_10154544563382892\n...etc`. Does your code print any messages?

Comment: This code nothing effect in the database. But the commented lines effects on database, using this I am getting all the id. Where as my requirement is to get the id of message only.

Comment: but you have not an associative array at `$total_posts[0]` due `$total_posts[0] = array('message', 'story', 'created_time', array('date', 'timezone_type', 'timezone'),'id');`. Can you update your question, I don't figure out what you need to see finally. What kind of record you want to save into database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I have understand the question right.

here you can remove some lines of code (no validity check included)

> ```
> $total_posts = array();
> $posts_response = $posts_request->getGraphEdge();
> do {
>     $response_array = $posts_response->asArray();
>     $total_posts = array_merge($total_posts, $response_array);  
> } while ($posts_response = $fb->next($posts_response))
> $array = json_encode($total_posts, true);
> ```

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("insert into `<table>` (`id`,`message`) values(?,?);");
    $message_ids = array();
    $stories = array();
    foreach ($total_posts as $row) {
        if (isset($row['message'])) {
            // any record with 'message' is allowed
            // whenever has it 'story' or no
            $message_ids[] = $row['id'];
            $stories[]     = $row['message'];

        } else {
            if (isset($row['story'])) {
                // only story
            } else {
                // no message & no story
            }
        }
    }

    $message_id = implode("\n",$message_ids);
    $story      = implode("\n",$stories);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $message_id, $story);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        // success
    } else {
        // error handler
        $error = $stmt->error;
        // debug
        echo $error.PHP_EOL;
        die();
    }

    // or output to console
    // echo 'id: '.$message_id.PHP_EOL;
    // echo 'message: '.$story.PHP_EOL;
    // echo PHP_EOL;    
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // debug
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Updated results:

```
id: 10154521329397892_1015455584936789210154521329397892_1015454259720289210154521329397892_10154542027992892
msg: Insane!!!!!R.I.P JaihindJohnson & Johnson Finally Admits: Their Baby Products Contain Cancer-Causing Chemicals |
```

I have no issues with database:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> use test;
Database changed

mysql> create table `test` (`id` varchar(128), `msg` varchar(128));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,10 sec)

mysql> show tables;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_test |
+----------------+
| test           |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> explain `test`;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | varchar(128) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| msg   | varchar(128) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0,01 sec)

mysql>

/// console
[65] $ php ./a.php
id: 10154521329397892_10154555849367892
10154521329397892_10154542597202892
10154521329397892_10154542027992892
msg: Insane!!!!!
R.I.P Jaihind
Johnson & Johnson Finally Admits: Their Baby Products Contain Cancer-Causing Chemicals |

 /// back to mysql shell
mysql> select * from `test`;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id                                                                                                        | msg                                                                                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 10154521329397892_1015455584936789210154521329397892_1015454259720289210154521329397892_10154542027992892 | Insane!!!!!R.I.P JaihindJohnson & Johnson Finally Admits: Their Baby Products Contain Cancer-Causing Chemicals |  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: @user1328007 , and no any errors messages? :( , I've updated the code, can you try it?

Comment: No error. I think we have to enter the condition before inserting into the database. I would like to insert the value of "id" when ever there is a "message" key from the given example in the json format. So in the example I have exactly 3 message_id

Comment: @user1328007 ,  are you sure, that you have opened database, correct sql-query and corresponding table structure? I have tested the code, it shows result correct.

Comment: Its coming, but not the exact way which I want, I want that in my db, all message_id should be one field, and all message should be another field. But your code creates rows as the total number of message id exists

Comment: Ah.. any item separator needed?

Comment: no, now,  the id and message are blank in the database

Comment: @user1328007 , I have no any issues with mysql database, see the answer. Where is your database located, maybe you need to check connection params?

Comment: No the output which you have shows is not the format which I want. all messages should be one field and corresponding id should be in one field, and each message should be in one line as well as id should be in one line. I have given the sample in the question, please have a look

Comment: you said - "database is blank" ... id and messages can be separated via line feed character.. just change `$message_id = implode('',$message_ids);` to `$message_id = implode("\n",$message_ids);` and do the same for `$stories`

Comment: same no effect, Please have a look in the code http://pastebin.com/FtQcnkxf and the database http://screenshot.co/#!/ff2396f574

Comment: omg.. I've mistypes ) Checked out your code.. https://www.dropbox.com/s/phxpr5b9sr4137z/839a252f7a.jpg .. and found a problem.. "\n" doesn't affect on the saved value :(

Comment: done, there was a mistake in variable message_id shoild be in place of message_ids and Story in place of stories, Thanks a lot

Comment: @user1328007 you want on line one: id + title and on line two: same_id + story ?

Comment: @Wizard, I was trying to store the same in two tables one is row wise and another is all in one field, the code is http://pastebin.com/wKQwrWQb but getting error 
Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in /home/anupaoe4/public_html/fbtest/index.php on line 153

Comment: @user1328007 you need to initialize variables as arrays before loop

Comment: Done ! there was some issues in variable

Comment: @Wizard, After implementing the code and testing it with the data what I found that data are inserting two time. http://pastebin.com/xM7378qa But I am not able to find the reason. Could you please have a look

Comment: Hi @Wizard, I got a strange from this code http://pastebin.com/YGDeDshH, When I run the program in some cases, Line no 14 : print_r($posts_response); executes  where as in other cases if parts executes. But both cases scenario is same. Is there anything wrong in validation please.

Comment: @user1328007 , your code is slightly wrong.. now it skips the first page of result and add twice the next pages in one case, and `print_r` response in other case

Comment: @Wizard, I did because, previously it was like this http://pastebin.com/sQctzEYc, but in this case I am not getting the data of some users (e.g. http://pastebin.com/M2xEg9S2, this output I got just putting the print_r($posts_response); before line number 90 ), it seems that in the given code  Else-part is working  but not if-part. Please help

Comment: @Wizard, This is pastebin.com/YGDeDshH basically used for paging purpose.

Comment: @Wizard, I dont know why I am not getting some of the users data, http://screenshot.co/#!/e97390750a, here is the code http://pastebin.com/hsYahivD,

Comment: @Wizard,   Earlier also I have tried like the way said, but it gives me nothing in the database, after json_encode, I did print_r, even it dint show me anything on the screen. this is the code http://pastebin.com/96305MBH. But if I did other way like http://pastebin.com/ipGdVvEB, I am not able to fetch the data of some users

Comment: @user1328007 , I don't have any issues with this code http://pastebin.com/iA9Z1X26

Comment: @Wizard, I tried the same way, I am hitting my head to get the bugs in the code ! Thanks

Comment: @Wizard, it seems that users made the settings private , thats why I am not able to get the messages